# graphicsmagick gm convert -size -resize scales up small images even with "w x h >"

Tags: image, resize, geometry, image-resizing, graphicsmagick

When using something like the following on an image that's `100x400 px` I end up with a file that's `192x768 px`:

`gm convert -size 1024x768 #{source[:filename]} -resize \"1024x768>\" +profile \"*\" #{source[:web_filename]}`

The `>` in `1024x768>` [change[s] the dimensions of the image only if its width or height exceeds the geometry specification](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-geometry).

But I guess that does not work because a size of `1024x768` is specified in `-size 1024x768`.

I base that on the docs saying `-size` [specifies the width x height of the image](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-size) so it does not check the image headers.

I do not want to lose any performance advantage by not specifying `-size`, as suggested in the [resize example](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html) but I don't want to scale up images either, so is there a better way to do this (or have I got the wrong end of the stick with what I said above)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what `#{source[:filename]}` or `#{source[:web_filename]}` represent in your command above, however, one thing I suspect you are misunderstanding is the `-size` parameter - the first parameter in your example.

The parameter `-size` ***only*** specifies the size of a canvas that **GraphicsMagick** is about to create itself, such as for a following `xc:`, a following `gradient:`, a following `label:`. It does not alter or change the size of anything.

```
# Create a solid blue canvas 100x100
gm convert -size 100x100 xc:blue ...

# Create a red-blue gradient 400x50
gm convert -size 400x50 gradient:red-blue ...
```

Comment: #{source[:xyz]} are just variables (copied and pasted there sorry). I was able "fix" this by removing the -side option. So I guess specifying a canvas size larger than the image means `>` can't work. Makes sense but wanted to check there isn't a better way though.